# TemplateDoesNotExist error for a simple ModelAdmin example

Tags: wagtail

I've used Wagtail's `ModelAdmin` on a few other projects with great success, but this is the first time I'm attempting to use it with a model inheriting from `Page`.

I copied the [simple example](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html#a-simple-example) template and removed the parts that didn't relate to my `BlogPageModel`.

The link to the `ModelAdmin` appears as expected, but when I click it, I get `TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/blog/blogpage/`.

I don't remember having to set up a template before. Is there a setting I'm missing?

Wagtail: 1.9 /
Django: 1.10.5 /
Python: 3.5.2

Update: I tried it with a model that inherits from `models.Model` as well with the same result.

Traceback follows:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/blog/blogpage/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 109, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 84, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 66, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 53, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: modeladmin/blog/blogpage/index.html, modeladmin/blog/index.html, modeladmin/index.html
[21/Feb/2017 07:56:38] "GET /admin/blog/blogpage/ HTTP/1.1" 500 110901
```

Comment: Could you post the full error message including the stack trace, please?

Comment: Sure thing, @gasman. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I suspect you've missed out adding `'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: <face palm> Thanks. I erroneously saw it in there when I scanned it earlier.

Comment: Also face-palm, I had an issue where my menu-item wasn't showing up. `'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin'` needs to be added _after_ the app that needs to consume it.